# AG Grid filterModel applies in community version but not in enterprise?

Tags: ag-grid

This following snippet works as expected in the AG Grid Community package, but does not seem to do so for the enterprise version. Why is this?

Codepen available [here](https://codepen.io/imdavidmin-the-flexboxer/pen/LYXYgyg?editors=1010) to test.

```
gridOptions.api.setFilterModel({
    employee_name: {
      filter: "C",
      type: "startsWith",
      filterType: "text"
    }
  });
gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default filter is SetFilter for Enterprise and TextFilter for Community. When you put in `agTextFilter`, it's invalid, and defaults back in enterprise version to Set, which made your filter not apply.

If you correct your filter from `agTextFilter` to `agTextColumnFilter` in your columnDefs then your example will work.

```
var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columns.map(([field, label]) => {
    return {
      field: field,
      filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
      headerName: label
    }
  }),
  rowData: data
}
```

Hope that helps